# Показать пользователю диалог, блокирующий выполнение длительного процесса

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте!

Есть длительный процесс, ход которого отображается в диалоге, построенном на `SwingWorker-е`. В ходе процесса мне нужно спросить нечто у пользователя и пока он не ответит процесс не продолжать. Обычный `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` не прорисовывается, а `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` продолжает исполнять основной поток. Если я начинаю эти потоки синхронизировать круг замыкается - снова не прорисовывается диалог с вопросом. 
Кто знает как эту ситуацию победить?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте статический флаг. Из потока опрашивайте его.

```
public volatile boolean canContinue;
run(){
    ...
    while (!XXX.canContinue){
        try{Thread.Sleep(10);}
        catch(ThreadInterruptedException e){}
    }
}
```

Comment: canContinue не вполне подходит. Мой вопрос может появиться, а может и нет на определённом этапе работы потока. Т.е на окне с прогресс баром я не могу его заранее опубликовать, требуется дополнительный диалог.